# angular loop through nested json array

Tags: angularjs

I have the following json structure

```
     "bonds": [
{
  "name": "bond_0",
  "interface": [
    "nic_0",
    "nic_1"
  ],
  "mode": "active_standby",
  "primary_interface": "nic_0"
},
{
  "name": "bond_1",
  "interface": [
    "nic_0",
    "nic_1"
  ],
  "mode": "active_standby",
  "primary_interface": "nic_0"
}
```

]

I need to loop and display the data in a table. although I can display all the values ihave trouble to display the interface array. I tried to do this with ng-repeat="interface in bond.interfaces but it is not working.
your help will be appreciated 
at my view  the code is

```
<table class="table">
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>interface</th>
              <th>mode</th>
              <th>primary interface</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="bond in bonds">
              <td><div>{{bond.name}}</div></td>
              <td><table><tr ng-repeat="interface in bond.interfaces"><td>{{interface}}</td></tr></table></td>
              <td>{{bond.mode}}</td>
              <td>{{bond.primary_interface}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Comment: Typo? interface v/s interface`s`. Also is the object `bonds` assigned directly to the scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your code from

```
<tr ng-repeat="interface in bond.interfaces">
```

to

```
<tr ng-repeat="interface in bond.interface">
```

bond has interface as a property. So bond.interface will work.